# Chrome drive installation failing behind proxy

Tags: npm, npm-install

I'm trying to install chromedriver using npm and I'm behind my corporate proxy. I'm seeing the following errors.

This is what I did so far

1. I've set my proxy config like
   npm config set proxy http://proxy.na.xxxxx.com:8080
   npm config set proxy http://proxy.na.xxxxx.com
2. I've cleared cache 
   npm config delete proxy
3. npm install chromedriver --ignore_ssl

None of them helped

---

```
ChromeDriver installation failed Error with http request: { 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  pragma: 'no-cache',
  'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
  'proxy-connection': 'close',
  connection: 'close',
  'content-length': '727' }
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN minos-carrier@3.1.0 No license field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\#####\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "chromedriver"
npm ERR! node v6.9.2
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! chromedriver@2.28.0 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the chromedriver@2.28.0 install script 'node install.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the chromedriver package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node install.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs chromedriver
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls chromedriver
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
npm install chromedriver@2.29.0 --chromedriver-cdnurl=http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com
```

The module specific cdnurl option (chromedriver-cdnurl) with http (instead of https) would address the stricken ca certification check issue in certain corporate proxy env.

Answer (score 1):

I worked around `chromedriver` failing to connect via a proxy by downloading the binary and pointing `chromedriver` to it.  For example:

```
curl https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.46/chromedriver_win32.zip > x:\chromedriver.zip
npm install chromedriver@2.46 --chromedriver_filepath=x:\chromedriver_win32.zip
```